# Trello: How to send new comment to all members of a team and not to all members of the board

Tags: trello, trello-boards

In trello one can use **@board** when writing a comment so that all members of the board will be notified of the new comment.

Is is possible to do something similar but only for team members? I have created a new team but I cannot find how to do it. I tried things like `@team` but it is apparently not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is currently not possible.** Mentioning all board members (using `@board`) is the broadest scope you can currently use to notify others of new comments.

(In fact, [even mentioning individual team members](https://help.trello.com/article/765-commenting-on-cards) will *not* send them a notification, if they are currently not members of the board you are working from.)